# R class or structure

Tags: r

I'm searching for something like a class or a structure in R like this:

```
class
{
  int i[10];
  char bla[10]

  float v[10][10]
}
```

Do I have to pack it in 3 different frames? Or how this is done?

Comment: Excuse me, but did you use a search engine before asking this question? Even in "An Introduction to R" the `class` keyword is mentioned. Have a look for "OOP in R", "S3 classes", "S4 classes", "ReferenceClasses" ...

Comment: you are right, tried in rstudio search function but in the wrong chapter :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. There are two types of classes system in R.You can check out following help page for more info. `?setClass` and `?class`